# MATCH on nodes in a two-dimensional COLLECTION in Neo4j / Cypher

Tags: collections, neo4j, match, cypher

In order to limit traversal through a Neo4j graph db, I am collecting scores from a subgraph. Imagine this (simplified)

```
MATCH (a)-[:r1 {prop1:123}]->()-[]->()-[]->()-[]->(b {prop2:456}) 
WITH b,b.prop2*r1.prop1 as score ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10
WITH COLLECT ([b,score]) AS bscore
```

so far, so good. To avoid the long traversal, I want to limit the next match to the nodes b stored in bscore and sum the scores in bscore[1], but I couldn't find the correct syntax. Even wondering whether it's possible in  cypher. Conceptually I'd like to do this:

```
MATCH bscore[0]-[:r2]->(c)
RETURN c, SUM(bscore[1])
```

Any hints/ pointers highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you do something like this perhaps?

```
MATCH (a)-[:r1 {prop1:123}]->()-[]->()-[]->()-[]->(b {prop2:456}) 
WITH b,b.prop2*r1.prop1 as score ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10
MATCH b-[:r2]->(c)
RETURN c, sum(score)
```

Comment: typo in r1:prop1 though.. should be r1.prop1

Comment: You can shorten the long anonymous pattern as well to (a)-[:r1]->()->[*3]->(b)

Comment: it was just an example to show that the (a) node can be somewhere far way and I wished to avoid recovering the entire path to it